# Power Query – Combining Text.PadStart and Text.TrimStart

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm combining data from several sources and multiple years – the information coding standard has changed over the years, and I'm trying to align everything to the current standard.

Can my code below be optimized? Just want to make sure, I'm not doing something silly...

To align the data entries to the same standard I ended up using this "monstrosity":

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Location", 
 {{"ActivityCode",
 each Text.PadStart(Text.TrimStart(_,"0"), 4 , "0"),
 type text}}
 )
```

Here are some examples of data entries in the same column:

```
09999 [expected to be 9999]
00200 [expected to be 0200]
99995 [ok]
01200 [expected to be 1200]
00997 [expected to be 0997]
  200 [expected to be 0200]
 7000 [ok]
```

The code works, albeit looks *newbish*. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Looks fine to me. M can look complex when you're not used to it.